# Buttons in android : Visible, Invisible, Gone

Tags: java, android, crash

I am working on android app and need to define custom buttons.

Initially, I am setting the button to Invisible.

I want to execute a particular method, and check for a String value. If it returns null value, then the button should be still invisible. If it returns some string value, I want to invoke the button and perform some task then.

This is what I tried, but failing.

My app is crashing when the code value returns Null, with error : "attempt to invoke virtual method"

```
 public String code = "";
 Button startbtn;
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_retrieve_visits);

    startbtn = findViewById(R.id.videobutton);
    startbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //code
        }
    });
//more code here
}

public void parseData(String response)
{
 try {
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(response);
        JSONArray data = json.getJSONArray("data");
        for (int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++) 
        {
            JSONObject child = data.getJSONObject(i);
            code = child.getString("code");
        }

        if(data.length()==0) ////check for empty array
            startbtn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        else
            startbtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: can you provide full code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try the code below

```
 if (code != null && !code.equels("")
        {
            startbtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        else
        {
            startbtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        startbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            //Required action
        }
```

Comment: Tried these. NullPointException :Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void.android.widget.button.setvisibilty(int)' on a null object reference

Comment: have you define button with findViewById show your full code of activity.

Comment: see updated ans and make sure videobutton is in activity_retrieve_visits.xml

Answer (score 1):

You can set a button in three ways in android:
1. VISIBLE
2. INVISIBLE
3. GONE

Use `button.INVISIBLE` to hide button instead of `button.GONE` as latter one removes button from view instead of hiding. This is the reason you are getting null pointer exception.

Answer (score 0):

You may try the below code:

```
    if (code == null || code.equals("")
    {
        startbtn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
    else
    {
        startbtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
```

If the value in code is null or is empty, we set the button to invisible else it will be visible.